# Referencing another schema in moongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to build a simple web where user post images and other users are able to comment on that image but i've stuck while referencing other schema.

schema for camground.js, comment has an empty array while checking in camgrounds collection.

```
    var mongoose = require("mongoose");

    var campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
       name: String,
       image: String,
       description: String,
       comments: [
          {
             type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
             ref: "Comment"
          }
       ]
    });


module.exports = mongoose.model("Campground", campgroundSchema);
```

comment schema.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    text: String,
    author: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);
```

i've hardcoded comment here in seeds.js and also used populate here but camground collections do not have an object id of comment, please help.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Campground = require("./models/campground");
var Comment   = require("./models/comment");

var data = [
    {
        name: "Cloud's Rest", 
        image: "https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3795/10131087094_c1c0a1c859.jpg",
        description: "blah blah blah"
    },
    {
        name: "Desert Mesa", 
        image: "https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3859/15123592300_6eecab209b.jpg",
        description: "blah blah blah"
    },
    {
        name: "Canyon Floor", 
        image: "https://farm1.staticflickr.com/189/493046463_841a18169e.jpg",
        description: "blah blah blah"
    }
]

function seedDB(){
   //Remove all campgrounds
   Campground.remove({}, function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("removed campgrounds!");
         //add a few campgrounds
        data.forEach(function(seed){
            Campground.create(seed, function(err, campground){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    console.log("added a campground");
                    //create a comment
                    Comment.create(
                        {
                            text: "This place is great, but I wish there was internet",
                            author: "Homer"
                        }, function(err, comment){
                            if(err){
                                console.log(err);
                            } else {
                                campground.comments.push(comment);
                                campground.save();
                                console.log("Created new comment");

                              // console.log(comment);
                            }
                        });
                }
            });
        });
    }); 
    //add a few comments
}

module.exports = seedDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
campground.comments.push(comment);
```

Do

```
campground.comments.push(comment._id);
```

**EDIT:**

Wrote a quick script to test your scenario. See the script below. It works fine all the entities are getting saved to database along with **comments**. Have attached result from mongo after running the script. Check if i am missing something

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   image: String,
   description: String,
   comments: [
      {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "Comment"
      }
   ]
});


var Campground = mongoose.model("Campground", campgroundSchema);

var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    text: String,
    author: String
});

var Comment = mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);

var data = [
    {
        name: "Cloud's Rest", 
        image: "https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3795/10131087094_c1c0a1c859.jpg",
        description: "blah blah blah"
    },
    {
        name: "Desert Mesa", 
        image: "https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3859/15123592300_6eecab209b.jpg",
        description: "blah blah blah"
    },
    {
        name: "Canyon Floor", 
        image: "https://farm1.staticflickr.com/189/493046463_841a18169e.jpg",
        description: "blah blah blah"
    }
]

function seedDB(){
   //Remove all campgrounds
   Campground.remove({}, function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("removed campgrounds!");
         //add a few campgrounds
        data.forEach(function(seed){
            Campground.create(seed, function(err, campground){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    console.log("added a campground");
                    //create a comment
                    Comment.create(
                        {
                            text: "This place is great, but I wish there was internet",
                            author: "Homer"
                        }, function(err, comment){
                            if(err){
                                console.log(err);
                            } else {
                                campground.comments.push(comment._id);
                                campground.save();
                                console.log("Created new comment");
                            }
                        });
                }
            });
        });
    }); 
}

function dbInit(){
    var MONGODB_SERVER = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
     mongoose.connect(MONGODB_SERVER, (err)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log('------- Not connecting to database --------');
        }else{
            console.log('------ Database connected -------');
            seedDB();
        }
    });
}

dbInit();
```

**Result:**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b5c4d0d97529908f180ff35"), "comments" : [ ObjectId("5b5c4d0e97529908f180ff38") ], "name" : "Cloud's Rest", "image" : "https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3795/10131087094_c1c0a1c859.jpg", "description" : "blah blah blah", "__v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b5c4d0d97529908f180ff36"), "comments" : [ ObjectId("5b5c4d0e97529908f180ff39") ], "name" : "Desert Mesa", "image" : "https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3859/15123592300_6eecab209b.jpg", "description" : "blah blah blah", "__v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b5c4d0d97529908f180ff37"), "comments" : [ ObjectId("5b5c4d0e97529908f180ff3b") ], "name" : "Canyon Floor", "image" : "https://farm1.staticflickr.com/189/493046463_841a18169e.jpg", "description" : "blah blah blah", "__v" : 1 }
```

Comment: Thanks, now it worked. Don't know why it was not working before.